# Maintain equal height on resize (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, height, equals

I use this code for equalizing columns:

```
jQuery.fn.equalHeight=function() {
var maxHeight=0;
this.each(function(){
 if (this.offsetHeight>maxHeight) {maxHeight=this.offsetHeight;}
});
this.each(function(){
 $(this).height(maxHeight + "px");
 if (this.offsetHeight>maxHeight) {
  $(this).height((maxHeight-(this.offsetHeight-maxHeight))+"px");
 }
});
};
```

..does a decent job, but I have an accordion menu in one of those columns which slides in/out changing the height of the column, equalheight doesn't play nice with it. Is it possible to equalize the columns each time they're resized?

Thanks heaps!

Comment: Even tried with setTimeout and setInterval, doesn't work. :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, this works great cross-browser:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.equalHeight = function(){
        var height = 0,
            reset = $.browser.msie ? "1%" : "auto";

        return this
            .css("height", reset)
            .each(function() {
                height = Math.max(height, this.offsetHeight);
            })
            .css("height", height)
            .each(function() {
                var h = this.offsetHeight;
                if (h > height) {
                    $(this).css("height", height - (h - height));
                };
            });

    };

})(jQuery);
```